# admin/people/permissions no access

Tags: 7, users

I can not access `admin/people/permissions`, even the link to permissions in the backend-menu is not visible. But I am logged in as admin! So what can be the problem here?

Comment: So what happens when you access the URL? Is this fresh install? Please provide more info in your question.

Comment: if I try to access the URL, I get an error, that I dont have the rights to access. it is a bigger project, that was build by someone else...

Answer (score 4):

Your administrative role probably lacks the "administer permissions" permission.

If you have Drush installed:

```
$ drush role-add-perm 'administrator' 'administer permissions'
```

You may also want to make sure your site still defines the 'administrator' role, since occasionally developers may manually delete the default roles from the DB (really not a good idea unless you know what you're doing). If you can't view available roles you can run this Drush command:

```
$ drush role-list
```

If it's not there, then you may have to create a new role to replace the admin role that was deleted and assign the role to yourself, and give your new role the 'administer permissions' permission:

```
$ drush role-create 'administrator'
$ drush user-add-role 'administrator' 'your username'
$ drush role-add-perm 'administrator' 'administer permissions'
```

If for some reason you don't have terminal access to your server, then you may need to download and enable the Devel module and PHP filter, then write a script that you can paste and run in /devel/php, but that should really be your last resort. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/56495/72084

p.s.: I believe Drupal gives user 1 the administrator role and completely unrestricted access by default. So if you are logged in as someone other than user 1, and/or if the administrator role has been deleted, that may explain how this problem came about. https://www.drupaleasy.com/quicktips/beginner-tip-what-special-about-drupal-user-1

Comment: indeed, I don`t have drush-access to the site.
But I  can create a new user with admin rights. But the problem persists...

Comment: Have you been able to grant the "Administer Permissions" permission to admin users? Are you able to log in as user 1? https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428

Comment: Thank you, this led me down the right path, though _no one_ had the permissions, uh, permission. The original creators of the site I'm troubleshooting used the French spelling of administrator (administrateur). And though the role id, etc is still the same, I'm noticing multiple oddities. Including that new modules had their permissions assignment to "disabled."

Answer (score 0):

simple solution - but hard to find: it was a problem with a backend theme. Changed to the standard theme for backend and can access permissions and the link/tab is here again.

Comment: ok. that seemed the solution, but could not be verified on the production site. so I am still looking for a solution